# Selenium click function is not getting Fail

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, testng, ui-automation

The below code is written for click function.

```
public void click(By element) {

    try {
    driver.findElement(element).click();
    }
    catch (AssertionError e) {
        System.out.println("Element " + element + " not found on page");
        return;
}
}
```

The below code is written for calling the click function in my test case.

```
    @Test(priority = 1)
public void accept_cookies_dialog() throws Exception {

    try {

        click(By.id(propObjctRepo.getProperty("id_cookieCta")));


    } catch (Exception e) {
        addErrorlogs(e, "Not found accpet cookie dialog.");
    }

}
```

My concern is, In every case either the element present or not the test case is getting pass. I am doing something wrong, Please suggest me the solution.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using `try/catch` block, you can directly use assertions to check if the element is present on the page or not. If the list size of the element is greater than zero then the element is present on the page else it is not. By this, if the element is not present on the page, assertion will fail and so will the test case.

You can do it like:

```
Assert.assertTrue(driver.findElements(By.id(propObjctRepo.getProperty("id_cookieCta"))).size()>0);
```

And then below this you can click the element, so if and only if the assertion passes, your code will reach the `click` method else your test case will fail.

Comment: Yeah agreed, the try catch loops are consuming any Exceptions you are getting, meaning the test doesn't fail as the exceptions are handled in the code. You either need to add in an assertion like Sameer suggests before the click without a try catch or get rid of the try/catch loops you currently have to allow the exceptions to be thrown, which would cause a failure.